# android included layout control shows null pointer exception

Tags: android

I have tried many things for layout Inflater etc.
but not able to access Toggle button control.
PostActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        View shareView = findViewById(R.id.in_shareLayout);


 tbFb = (ToggleButton) shareView.findViewById(R.id.tbFb);
   tbFb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // Save the state here
                Log.e("I Am Tired!", "tired--> " + isChecked);
            }
        });
        tbFb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("I Am Tired!", "tired--> ");

            }
        });
```

In above class onClick or checked changed listeners are not fired.
and it always shows false value

Included Layout sharecontent_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:text="share on"
    />
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    style="@style/fbtoggleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/fbsharebg"
    android:id="@+id/tbFb"/></LinearLayout>
```

This is my Layout PostActivity.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/share_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/in_shareLayout"
                layout="@layout/sharecontent_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your log.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass layout filename.

Change your:

```
layout="@layout/sharecontent_layout"
```

to

```
layout="@layout/ShareLayout"
```

---

Also

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
```

To

```
setContentView(R.layout.PostActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't find view this way

```
View shareView = findViewById(R.id.in_shareLayout);
```

remove this

you can directly access your included layout control

```
tbFb = (ToggleButton) shareView.findViewById(R.id.tbFb);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

layout1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="share on"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tbFb"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/in_shareLayout"
        layout="@layout/layout1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DemoActivity.java

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbFb);
        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.e("Demo", "===================="+isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and above code is worked for me i have tested it

Comment: I also tried that it shows  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: you have to remove setOnClickListener from tbFb.

Comment: not solved same error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: i also used merge tag inside included layout

Comment: and also not get tbFb.isChecked() value it shows null reference error

Comment: check my modify answer i have tested code and its worked.

Comment: Thank You your demo is working but not in my case .. is there any problem with my toggle button style?

Comment: This is the Log shows when it is inside onCreate() for Listener                                 07-08 14:11:14.590  21094-21094/com.bazingalabs.socioadvocacy W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference